# JQuery function as var, and then executing var on action

Tags: jquery, function, variables, triggers, execute

I have a function:

```
var oneWay = function (){
    $(".one-way").show();
    $(".round-trip").hide();
    $(".multi-stop").hide();
 };
```

I want to trigger this function on an action, i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[value=one-way]").click('oneWay');
});
```

But this isn't working. I think my syntax might be off.

Also, what if I wanted to just execute this function when the DOM is ready? Would it be this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   oneWay; 
});
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what DavidGouge said.  Further, to answer your other question, you just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[value=one-way]").click(oneWay); //binds it to the click event
    oneWay(); //executes it now.
});
```

Remember that `oneWay` is a reference to a function (passed as an "object"), while `oneWay()` executes that function immediately.

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to execute multiple functions on a single trigger?

Comment: That's when you want to pass in an anonymous function:  `$('#elem').click(function() { oneWay(); secondWay(); });`

Answer (score 3):

Removing the quotes should be enough...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[value=one-way]").click(oneWay);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[value=one-way]").click(oneWay);
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[value=one-way]").click(function(){ oneWay(); });
});
```

and the last:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //oneWay;
   oneWay(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Click takes as it's argument a function literal, not a string name of a function literal.

See [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/MAbzr/).

And the pertinent modification:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[value=one-way]").click(oneWay); // no quotes here, just the variable
});
```